# How to accept subscription payments for services on my website that would go to multiple users

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, paypal-adaptive-payments, payment-processing

I am building an application that has two types of users: owners and buyers.
When a user signs up for a payment subscription to the services offered on the website, the system checks to which owner those selected services belong to and should then make that subscription payment go to that owner. So basically, users have no idea that payments go to multiple people. As far as they are concerned, they are just selecting certain services on our website and signing up for a monthly recurring subscription payment. The system then decides where that subscription money should go.

So, how can I do this? What possible systems can I use? I have looked into two: PayPal and Stripe. I can see how I might be able to use them for this if I get really creative, however I just wanted to ask you guys to see if any one has experience in doing something like this and what is a good way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: I would go with PayPal and look at reference transactions or preapproved payment profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're description about [PayPal Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/), you need setup [preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/) and [Chained Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) .

In this scenario, you act as Primary Receiver. You can setup the payment that Primary Receiver keep certain percentage amount ($10 in in 2nd picture), or distribute all payment to multiple receivers (service providers). It's up to your business logic.

[image: Chained Payment]

[image: Chained Payment]